# What happen if i use ngOnInit method without implementing OnInit interface

Tags: angular, angular-component-life-cycle

Can anyone please tell me what will happen if I don't implement **onInit** interface and still using **ngOnInit** component lifecycle inside a component?

Since I used **ngOnInit** lifecycle hook without implementing an interface and it's worked for me the same.

**So just wanted to understand why I should implement an interface?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will still work as expected.

Interface helps us to **avoid spelling and syntax mistakes**.

According to recomendations from [Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#lifecycle-hooks)

> Lifecycle interfaces prescribe typed method signatures. Use those
>   signatures to flag spelling and syntax mistakes.